# Google Chrome stealing the Clipboard

Tags: c#, google-chrome, clipboard, chromium

I have a problem and I only came accross two or three posts around the web about it: When I'm using the clipboard in a C# application (Clipboard.SetText or Clipboard.Clear), Chrome is randomly already using it, so my clipboard request fails.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: Requested Clipboard operation did not succeed. 
    at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.ThrowIfFailed(Int32 hr)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(Object data, Boolean copy, Int32 retryTimes, Int32 retryDelay)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(String text, TextDataFormat format)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(String text)
```

I close Chrome, it works, then reopen Chrome, and after some minutes, it still fails. I'm using the following code with a 1 second timer and GetOpenClipboardWindow(), another PInvoke :(, to confirm that this is really Chrome that is annoying me:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetOpenClipboardWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int 
    lpdwProcessId);


    IntPtr hwnd = GetOpenClipboardWindow();
    if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        int processId;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out processId);
        Process p = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
        listBox1.Items.Add(p.Modules[0].FileName);
    }
```

Does any of you already had this problem? Do you know why Chrome is stealing the clipboard?

[Edit]

At any of the Chrome team members: Dear developer, if you read this today, give me my Clipboard back as I have more rights than you on my Clipboard. I've been searching for two days because of you.

Comment: Seems odd. Is it perhaps add-ons to Chrome that are doing this? Does it happen on other machines?

Comment: Also happened to this guy: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=86765

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid there is nothing left to do, If another process has the clipboard open, there is no way to free it until that process closes it.

Comment: That's right. It seems the only thing I could do was to handle the error and wait for Chrome to do its stuff. When it takes too long, I tell the user to restart or close the guilty program.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your app (because ultimately, that's all you can control) is playing by the rules.  Make sure that your are not doing multiple open/close operations when one will do.  For example, if you are placing multiple formats onto the clipboard, make sure that you encapsulate in ONE open/close block, not two.  Whenever you close the clipboard after updating, that generates clipboard notifications, which trigger other apps (that monitor the clipboard) to look at the new data.  So be sure that you generate ONE such event (not multiple) for each intended operation. Do not create unintended operations (i.e. don't open/close the clipboard for the heck of it when launching your app).  And if you have just updated the clipboard, don't expect that you can immediately read the clipboard without bumping heads with other apps that are reacting to the notification messages from windows (wm_DrawClipboard, etc.)